# CSS Star rating system not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs, rating-system

I'm trying to implement a star rating system for my react project. I have referred the following article to implement my star rating system.
I have implemented it properly but only problem is when i click a star, it won't stay colored. Instead it goes to the default mode when i move the mouse pointer away. But in this example i'm referring it works properly. What can be the issue here?

https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}


/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<fieldset className="rating">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label className = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label className="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label className = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label className="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label className = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label className="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label className = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label className="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label className = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label className="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code that *isn't* working, rather than the code you're copying that *is* working.

Comment: The code snippet is working fine  (?)

Comment: @JamieBarker in react you have to give the class as className.. so here,  the code snippet won't work if i give it className. Anyway i have updated my question

Comment: You can add React to code snippets. Look at the options on the left...

Comment: [Here you find how to set a class to the Element](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).
 @JamieBarker i deleted my answer. I wrote the answer, while the question got updated. Still the `React-Component`with `className` will be rendered as `<element class="definedClassName"></element>`

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Why don't you create a Plunker to replicate your issue? https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:a3vkhunC1Na5BG6GY2Gf